# Regex Help needed with field validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, coldfusion

I need to validate the field with the following requirements:

- must be at least 6 characters
- must be no more than 50 characters.
- must contain at least one alphabetical character
- There must be at least one "Other" character. 
  An "Other" character can only be either a number or any one of the following 8 characters:  underscore, hyphen, period, ampersand, dollar, star, exclamation, the @ symbol

I came up with the following regex but it does not always works it allows some special characters which I want to exclude

```
/^(?!.*(.)\1)((?=.*[^\w\d\s])(?=.*\w)|(?=.*[\d])(?=.*\w)).{6,50}$/
```

Comment: Why are you using a single regular expression? You cannot give the user proper feedback on why they failed.

Comment: @Bradley re: second sentence, ***sure*** you can. _"Dear user: your input did not match the following regular expression: `[snip]` Please go back and revise your input. For details see [http://regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info)."_

Comment: @Matt That would fit nicely on a geek website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you match with `.` at the end, so if all your conditions are met, then any leftover characters up to 50 can be anything. I would use:

```
/^(?=.{6,50}$)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\d_.&$*!@-])[a-zA-Z\d_.&$*!@-]*$/
```

Comment: @erik that is true, because in your 4 requirements you listed you didn't state any characters that you do not want to allow. Only minimum requirements. I'll edit my post to reflect allowing only `letters,numbers, and the symbols you said the must use at least one of`. I'm guessing that is what you want them to be restricted to?

Comment: sorry by the regex above does not validate anything at all

Answer (score 7):

Does it really have to be a regexp? I would just write a function that tests each of these criteria.

```
function isValid(password)
{
    return password.length >= 6 
        && password.length <= 50
        && password.match(/[A-Za-z]/)
        && password.match(/[0-9_\-.&$*!@]/);
}
```

Isn't that easier?

Comment: No, I'm sorry that looks too easy.  This should be a long complicated regex that, when read, makes you think the developer feel asleep on their keyboard after fainting due to a strong urge to drink 4Loco and Monster and Chronic in order to perpetuate the Programmer Image.

Comment: Whoah whoah whoah... what is all this toxic chemical spill sounding rubbish? In _my_ day, programmers drank coffee and Mountain Dew.

Comment: @erik - In addition to what Matt asked, any chance this is for a cfinput pattern?

Comment: @erik - Okay. Then could you explain why Matt's approach is not feasible for you? Because it is much simpler and the end result is the same.

Comment: @erik a tautological reason is not terribly useful. Sorry, I'm just trying to help you solve your problem, especially since no one else has posted a correct regex-based answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need the following:

(letters or symbols)*
letters+
symbols+
(letters or symbols)*

OR

(letters or symbols)*
symbols+
letters+
(letters or symbols)*